# Does "adb backup" also backup /data/misc/vold - the Encryption Key for Adoptable SD card?

Tags: adb, rooting, backup, encryption, adoptable-storage

I want to make sure that using `adb backup -apk -shared -all -f ~/backup.ab` will also save `/data/misc/vold`?

I am trying to backup before rooting, in order to be able to gain access to the encryption key in `/data/misc/vold` (got corrupted SD card adopted as internal). So I want to make sure ih something bad happens during the rooting, I could still access the backup version of `/data/misc/vold`?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't get backed up. For verification you can backup with that command, unpack the backup file and see the contents yourself.

Comment: Mmh, does not seem trivial to verify that by unpacking. Would that work anyway if I encrypted the system? More importantly, is there then a way to back up also /data/misc/vold ? Thanks!!

Comment: Try [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/96277) to unpack the backup file. As for `vold`, it can only be backed up using root access.

Comment: thanks! So you are saying that it is not possible to backup vold without being root? This is a conundrum, as I am precisely trying to root to access `vold`, and the process of rooting is likely to erase that file

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just not possible without root. :(

Comment: Related: [Is the Encryption Key for Adoptable SD card included in manual backup done over MTP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/206206/218526)

Comment: Related: [How to get Adoptable storage encryption key without root access after I "forget it"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181476)

Answer (score 2):

My solution to Matifow problem was ...

I cannot extract the token because my device was not rooted.

I bought a new microSD and clone in it the microSD from my device.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/227924/sd-card-cloning-using-the-dd-command

When i put this new card the phone recognize as the old one.

I recover photos, media from whatsapp, apps installed ...

I lost some files ( the corrupted I assume) but can recover the most.

Comment: nice idea! in case dd not working use gddrescue for cloning